# Can't Install DeSmuME on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: 14.04, games, emulation

I want to play DS on my laptop. But when I try to install DeSmuME it says that the package is broken.

```
xxx@xxx-IdeaPad-S210:~$ sudo apt-get install desmume
[sudo] password for xxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
desmume : Depends: libosmesa6 (>= 6.5.2-1) but it is not going to be      installed or libgl1-mesa-glide3 but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't install it directly, you can use [RetroArch](http://www.libretro.com/) with a Desmume core. Works great for me.

For Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04, you can install latest version from [Libretro PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libretro/+archive/ubuntu/stable). First install the PPA on your system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libretro/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

And then install Retroarch with Desmume core this way:

```
sudo apt-get install retroarch libretro-desmume
```

You can find more instructions on Libretro Forum. Check this [post](http://libretro.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1556).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Ubuntu bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/desmume/+bug/1422139) this seems like a confirmed bug.  The more specific bug related to this can be found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa-lts-utopic/+bug/1424059).  Current workaround based on the conversations is regression (regress to 14.04.1 or earlier).